# Symfony 3 rendering Form wrong Request

Tags: forms, methods, request, symfony

In symfony3 i have base view and inside this one im rendering other controller (this controller render form (return view with form - form is method POST)) when i try to use this one on the page object Request-isMethod() always return GET how to fix it.

Part of base view: (main controller show welcome page and render inside this one)

```
 <li><a>{{ render(controller('CommonUserBundle:Login:login')) }}</a></li>
```

Form login type

```
    class LoginType extends AbstractType
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'login_form';
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->
            add('username', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Użytkownik'
            ))
            ->add('password', PasswordType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Hasło'
            ))
            ->add('remember_me', CheckboxType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Zapamiętaj mnie'
            ))
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Zaloguj'
            ));
        }
}
```

Controller that render the form above

```
/**
     * @Route("/", name="login")
     *
     * @Template
     */
    public function loginAction(Request $Request)
    {
        $Session = $this->get('session');


        if($Request->attributes->has(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)){
            $loginError = $Request->attributes->get(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        } else {
            $loginError = $Session->remove(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        }

        $loginForm = $this->createForm(LoginType::class, array(
            'username' => $userName = $Session->get(Security::LAST_USERNAME)
        ));


        return array(
            'loginError' => $loginError,
            'loginForm' => $loginForm->createView()
        );
    }
```

Twig of above

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginForm">
    Zaloguj
</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="loginForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Logowanie</h4>
                {% if loginError is defined and loginError is not null %}
                    <div class="">
                        Blad i chuj: {{ loginError.message }}
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                {% form_theme loginForm 'bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig' %}
                {{ form(loginForm, {'action': path('_check_path')}) }}
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                {{ render(controller('CommonUserBundle:Login:rememberPassword')) }}
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Zamknij</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So as i said, i render this form on other twig tempalte and after i click SUBMIT my Request->getMethod is GET. In html all is ok method="post", when i create other Route only to this form his own (not rendered) its working ok. How to change it to work ok?

Comment: I think this is because you render the form in an **<a>** tag.

Comment: i solve this problem, its not about <a>. if u render other controller which render form. Rendered form path is current path (not controller Route path) to work correct i had to manually change attr action and set path to the controller which render this form in rendered controller view

Comment: Can you update your question with what you have modified ?

Comment: @OlivierC i did many changes in my project, but if u are on page url1 (example): Base.html.twig and inside this template u will render other controller for example AcmeBlogBundle:Post:addPost (this controller render form and should send request 'POST' on same controller) but if other controller already rendered for u base.html.twig(welcome page) and have rendered Post:addPost then Post:addPost default action will send you to the same controller that rendered current page so it will not be addPost, to fix this problem i had to manually add path to rendered view form